# Suppose $f(x)=x(x-2)$ and $h(x)=e^{-2x}$. If $f(a)+h( \ln a ) =0$, show that $a^3-a^2-a-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose $f(x)=x(x-2)$ and $h(x)=e^{-2x}$. If $f(a)+h(\ln a ) =0$, show that 
$$a^3-a^2-a-1=0$$

My attempt:

$a(a-2) + \dfrac{1}{a^2}=0 \Rightarrow a^4-2a^3+1=0 \Rightarrow a^3 = \dfrac{1}{2-a}$

Then I try to show LHS = RHS, but to no avail. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: try factorizing the polynomial

Comment: Thanks. I know how to solve it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(a)=a(a-2)$ and $h(\ln a)=a^{-2}$,
\begin{align}
f(a)+h(\ln a)=a^2-2a+a^{-2} &=\frac{1}{a^2}(a^4-2a^3+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2}(a-1)(a^3-a^2-a-1)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Since $\ln a$ is defined, $a>0$. If $a=1$, then $f(1)+h(0)=0$, but $a^3-a^2-a-1\ne 0$. If $a\ne 1$, $a^3-a^2-a-1=0$.

Thus, you may be missing one condition in the problem: $a\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely. If $a^3-a^2-a-1=0$ and $b(b-2)+\frac1{b^2}=0$, then $a\not = b$

May be $a^3-a^2+a-1=0 \Rightarrow a^2(a-1)+(a-1)=(a-1)(a^2+1)=0 \Leftrightarrow a=1$

Then $a(a-2)+\frac1{a^2}=0 \Leftrightarrow a=1$